# I'm loading a value into a table using jQuery .load() that I also have tablesorter running on and can't sort by the externally loaded data

Tags: php, jquery, html, tablesorter, jquery-load

Because this is what is in the  tag when I view source after the html renders:

```
<td valign='top'><div id='mPer4881'></div><script> $( '#mPer4881' ).load( 'matching.php?uid=1755&oppid=4881 #mPer' );</script></td>
```

I obviously can't sort meaningfully on that value in tablesorter, although the script works correctly and returns either 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 or 100 on the actual page based on the my external php, which is also functioning properly.

My question is: is there a away to have the numerical value render instead of the script so it can be sortable via tablesorter?

Note: I initially had my php script in the table but need to load it externally because when I scaled it over a few hundred rows it slowed the page load significantly.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you just using php to build the table? Using ajax (load) will just spam your server for every table cell.

Comment: @Mottie Because it's a big table with a ton of queries to get the data and by using ajax I cut the load time from 32 seconds to less than half a second. I started out just building it with php but it didn't scale well

Comment: I would recommend that you consider switching to php and using the pager with ajax to only display a subset of your data... Also, script tags within the table are not a good idea. The reason is that when a sort occurs, the rows are detached and then added back in order... when the browser sees a script tag get inserted, it gets executed. So it's querying your server again.